# Prove that number of clubs is bigger than people

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, proof-writing

I have a question in linear algebra
But it can be solved without linear algebra, I tried hard but
The question is: there is a city where n people live, and there are clubs with odd number of people, but the intersection of two clubs is even number, prove that the number of clubs m is smaller or equal to n.
Thanks

Comment: I want to know how to use linear algebra to prove this

Comment: Which work exactly?

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29956/blocking-to-ask-a-question-for-a-beginner

Comment: What are you talking about?